# Dose aruco gives me pose of the marker wrt to the camera frame or the pose of the camera wrt to marker coordinate frame?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use it for the localization of my bot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234905/dose-aruco-gives-me-pose-of-the-marker-wrt-to-the-camera-frame-or-the-pose-of-the-camera-wrt-to-marker-coordinate-frame?/) by [ksgaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/26949/ksgaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Aruco provides you with the pose of the marker w.r.t the camera.

---

Originally posted by [Saurav Agarwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4339/saurav-agarwal/) with karma: 246 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0